# jquery datepicker hide on blur

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been looking up these forums on how to change my jquery datepicker to hide on focusout. Here is what my form element looks like.

```
<form:input path="weekEndingDate" class="{required:true} datepicker" placeholder="enter a value"/>
```

From what I have been reading the best way to do it would be to make it generic for all date pickers (which I am happy with) and do something like...

```
$(".hasDatepicker").on("focus", function(e) { $(this).datepicker("show"); });
$(".hasDatepicker").on("blur", function(e) { $(this).datepicker("hide"); });
```

But that doesn't seem to work for me for some reason.

The datepicker doesn't even show. I do however get it to show if I do...

```
// Date picker.
$( "#weekEndingDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
}); 

$('#weekEndingDate').focus(function() {
    $(this).datepicker("show");
  })
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? On inspection of the date field it definitely does have the hasDatepicker class on it as below

```
<input type="text" value="" class="{required:true} datepicker hasDatepicker" placeholder="enter a value" name="weekEndingDate" id="weekEndingDate">
```

Maybe this will help. On playing with this a bit more I've just been able to see that there is an error coming back when I try to use the more generic .hasDatepicker selector ...

```
TypeError: a jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js Line 530
```

thanks

Comment: I think your event focus or blur not working correctly !

Comment: did you mean like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m2epC/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I thought that was default behavior, what's the difference if the event handlers are omitted? Given the example, http://jsfiddle.net/yC35S/?

Comment: Sorry guys, I think i got the onblur bit wrong. What I actually want it to do is when the users mouse leaves either the input field or the calendar. What even would that be?